# How to set audience according to groups for SharePoint Site navigation using managed navigation term set

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-navigation

I was using Structured navigation for the site navigation and had nodes with specific audiences eg:- customers,Clerks. Because i needed 3 tear navigation i had switch to using managed navigation with term set,but now I cant find a way to set audience to specific nodes like structured navigation. So is there a way to customize term set nodes with specific audiences?

Answer (score 3):

Managed Metadata term set not support use Target Audience.

At the term set level, you have owner and stakeholders but these are 'administrative' roles or care takers, not security. you can not set group in term set for target audience.Please check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13a5e894-44c8-4b23-ad28-4f1aac4d886d/term-store-management-with-audience-targeting?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) link for more detail.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for  you answer.Is their any way in SharePoint  to have 3 tier navigation with specific audiences?

Comment: You can enable 3 level menu using master page changes in sharepoint. please check this link: https://blog.thehensongroup.com/2013/01/13/3/

Comment: Thank you,but i can not add more than 2 tiers from SharePoint navigation seetings. Is their a list where i can add more nodes to the structured navigation?

Comment: Yes it's not possible in OOTB structured navigation. You can achieve this functionality using custom coding. Please check this link for your reference :http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Create-a-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Menu-in-SharePoint-2013-with-SuiteBar-Branding-Delegate-Control.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately i cant follow that tutorial because i'm developing a SharePoint online solution which does not require SharePoint foundation.

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to do it out of the box, you can do an update to the **TopNavigationMenu** control and set the **MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels** to 3 from 1(default). The disadvantage is you can have only maximum 3 nested levels. 
  [image]

[Static Display Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.maximumdynamicdisplaylevels%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

- In case you want to have N levels of navigation menu and want to create it dynamically from a SharePoint List, I have created an article here that uses SuperFish jquery plugin which is really easy to set up. This works in SP Online as well as SP 2016.
  [image]

[SuperFish Plugin Implementation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-navigation-menu-for-sharepoint-using-superfish-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: Hi Priyan, Thank your answer, i managed set maximum level but i cant see your link for using a list for storing node data.

Comment: My Mistake. I have updated the link to the answer.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, can i  set audiences for the nodes using this method?

Comment: We will have to use JSOM, Check if user is present in a specific SPGroup. If he is not present we will have to use jQuery to hide the <li></li> for that specific node.